# How to make a REST call with a console application to the SEARCH REST API?

Tags: 2013, search, rest

I have created a console application by using this tutorial:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kaevans/archive/2014/03/02/building-a-sharepoint-app-as-a-timer-job.aspx

With some differences of course, in my console app, I want to make a rest call to the search api.

Read this: Giving the App Principal Permissions
Instead of using tenant manage as in the example I used this:

```
  <AppPermissionRequests>
    <AppPermissionRequest Scope="https://sharepoint/search" Right="QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal" />
  </AppPermissionRequests>
```

Then I went to “_layouts/AppInv.aspx”. 
And registered the app using the client id and the xml above.

Then I clicked on Trust it.

My app.config is like this:

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Sites"
             type="System.Configuration.NameValueSectionHandler"/>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="ClientId" value="xx-1c6c-45e7-8a2a-7364a705c836"/>
    <add key="ClientSecret" value="+xx="/>
  </appSettings>
  <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
    </startup>
  <Sites>
    <add key="site1" value="https://xx.sharepoint.com/sites/developersitecollection"/>
  </Sites>
</configuration>
```

Then my console app fails with Unauthorized Exception on the getresponde

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Sites");


            foreach (var key in config.Keys)
            {
                Uri siteUri = new Uri(config.GetValues(key as string)[0]);

                using (ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUri))
                {
                    string realm = TokenHelper.GetRealmFromTargetUrl(siteUri);
                    string accessToken =
                        TokenHelper.GetAppOnlyAccessToken(TokenHelper.SharePointPrincipal,
                        siteUri.Authority, realm).AccessToken;

                    HttpWebRequest endpointRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(siteUri +"/_api/search/query?querytext=%27*.pptx%27");
                    endpointRequest.Method = "GET";
                    endpointRequest.Accept = "application/json;odata=verbose";
                    endpointRequest.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
                    HttpWebResponse endpointResponse = (HttpWebResponse)endpointRequest.GetResponse();
                    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(endpointResponse.GetResponseStream());
                    var searchXml = new XmlDocument();
                    searchXml.LoadXml(reader.ReadToEnd()); 

                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have added this into the xml
AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true"

and now the code shows me a different error, already asked a question about that error here:

https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/96102/remote-server-returned-an-error-500-internal-server-error-when-using-rest-sea